# Why is this lighttpd url rewrite not workng?

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have the following mod_rewrite code for lighttpd, but it does not properly foreward the user:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":3041" { 
server.document-root = server_root + "/paste" 
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/([^/\.]+)/?$" => "?page=paste&id=$1")
}
```

It should turn the url `domain.com/H839jec` into `domain.com/index.php?page=paste&id=H839jec` however it is not doing that, instead it is redirecting everything to `domain.com`. I dont know much about mod_rewrite and would appreciate some input on why it is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
url.rewrite-once = ("^/(.*)$" => "/?page=paste&id=$1")
```

I don't know the exact issue in your code, but first the regex looks unnecessarily complicated and may not match what you expected it to match, and second you're redirecting to a query string where as I would expect you still need to redirect to a valid path before the query string, that's why I redirect to `/?page...` instead of just `?page...`.